# Fastest way to convert decimal to binary - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am doing `item.toString(2).padStart(len, '0')` to convert all my decimal numbers to binary.

But, it is taking too long `~500 milliseconds` in a looped `benchmark` for n = 1,000,000.

`.toString` is too slow for me. Is there any better and more optimized way to convert to binary?

```js
console.time();
const len = 8;
const binaries = [];
for (let item = 0; item < 1000000; item++) {
  const binary = item.toString(2).padStart(len, '0');
  // binaries.push(binary);
}
console.timeEnd();
```

Comment: Can you show your exact code you are testing with. You can write a loop with bitwise, not 100% that would be faster than the toString.

Comment: The `padStart()` could probably be removed too. I had to go and read the docs before I realised it isn't related to your question.

Comment: The fastest way without WebAssembly would be to create an Object whose keys are all of your decimals - then you can get the corresponding binary number simply by `convertTable[decimal]` which is O(1) operation.

Comment: I'd like to ask a different question - **why** would you need that to be faster? What are you doing - and is it not possible to optimize the other thing instead?

Comment: It seems odd to me that you're calling strings of 0's and 1's "binary", that format is actually a step *further* from representing those decimals in a *useful* binary data type. I suggest that you correct your question to say something like "binary strings" if that's actually what you need. It would be good to know *why* you need that format because there are other encodings that are more efficient than using 1's and 0's; Which may be a valid solution for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a loop with bitwise operators like this:

```
let result = "";
for(let i=len-1; i>=0; i--) result += (item >> i) & 1;
```

This benched about 61-83% faster than the `.toString()` implementation you're using on Chrome v79.0.3945.1117.

Here it is compared to your implementation in your snippet:

```js
const len = 8;
const binaries = [];
let binary;
console.time("toString");
for (let item = 100000; item > 0; item--) {
  binary = item.toString(2).padStart(len, '0');
}
console.timeEnd("toString");

console.time("loop");
for (let item = 100000; item > 0; item--) {
  binary = "";
  for(let i=len-1; i>=0; i--) binary += (item >> i) & 1;
}
console.timeEnd("loop");
```

Answer (score 0):

Decimal to binary(in array)

```js
//returns the binary values in an Array for a input decimal number.
function toBinary(number) {
   let qutnt = number;
   let remender = [];
  while(qutnt !==0){
     if(Number.isInteger(qutnt/2)){
       qutnt = qutnt/2;
       remender.unshift(0);
     }else if (qutnt>0){
         qutnt = (qutnt-1)/2;
        remender.unshift(1);
     }
  }
 return remender;
}
toBinary(1296);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).